# VIM Highlight Numbers in LineNumber Column based on .pdbrc file contents

Tags: vim

Hi so I am looking for a method for highlighting a subset of numbers in the LineNumber column of vim. Maybe highlight is a bad choice, it could be as simple as just changing the background/foreground color of specific numbers.

My example

`.pdbrc`

```
b ~/foo.py:3
b ~/foo.py:7
```

when I open `foo.py` in VIM I would like lines 3 and 7 to be highlighted or have a different background color than the rest of the line numbers.

Basically I am just looking for a way to visually tell me, in VIM, where I have breakpoints set up in a file as per my `.pdbrc`

From my searching I believe this is not possible, but I don't know how VIM works very well and as such I may be misinterpreting the stackoverflow posts I have read.

What I've got so far, this will return a list of line numbers from the `.pdbrc` how do I take this list of numbers and highlight them or change their background color conditionally in vimscript?

```
function! s:parse_pdbrc(cur_file_abs_path)
   " read the .pdbrc lines and search for current in
   let s:lines = readfile("~/.pdbrc")
   " parse the filepath to make it regexable
   let s:file = substitute(a:cur_file_abs_path, "/", "\/", "")
   let s:file = substitute(s:file, ".", "\.", "")
   let s:regex = join(['b\s+',s:file,':(\d+)'],'')
   " make some storage
   let s:alist = []
   " iterate over the lines
   for s:line in s:lines
      " check if cur_file in line
      let s:match = matchlist(s:line, s:regex)
      " if we have a match store it
      if !empty(s:match)
         let s:alist = add(s:alist, s:match[1])         
      endif
   endfor
   return s:alist
endfunction
```

Comment: You probably want to look into signs

Comment: I will take a look into this, thank you.